# MySQL Update Query to remove specific Html tag from all the "description" fields

Tags: html, mysql, sql, regex, magento

I have a Magento site in which each product has an anchor tag like `<a href="link">Content</a>` in their descrption field.

Now I want to remove this anchor tag along with it's content inside the tag, but keep the rest of description as it is.

Right now a sample description is like below:

```
<ul>
    <li>Cylinder head has been assembled to OEM specifications with using all new components like Cam shaft, valves and/or springs, buckets, shims etc. where applicable.</li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://sampledomain.com/media/wysiwyg/folder/file.pdf">All heads we supply pass through 24 points of quality check program.</a>
    </li>
    <li>Warranty: 1 year or 20,000 Kms factory warranty.</li>
    <li>
        <b>Kit Includes:</b>
    </li>
    <li>Fully assembled cylinder head</li>
    <li>VRS (Vehicle regrind set)</li>
    <li>Head gaskets (thickest grade)</li>
    <li>Head bolts</li>
    <li>Warranty card</li>
</ul>
```

Now I want it show up like below:

```
<ul>
    <li>Cylinder head has been assembled to OEM specifications with using all new components like Cam shaft, valves and/or springs, buckets, shims etc. where applicable.</li>
    <li>
    </li>
    <li>Warranty: 1 year or 20,000 Kms factory warranty.</li>
    <li>
        <b>Kit Includes:</b>
    </li>
    <li>Fully assembled cylinder head</li>
    <li>VRS (Vehicle regrind set)</li>
    <li>Head gaskets (thickest grade)</li>
    <li>Head bolts</li>
    <li>Warranty card</li>
</ul>
```

How can I do this with an Update query ?

Comment: does it contain only one anchor tags or multiple for each product?

Comment: show a real sample and the result you need ..

Comment: It has only one anchor tag, per product description. Updating my question to add description.

Comment: Some tasks are best left for application code, not SQL.

Answer (score 1):

This will does the job ..!

```
UPDATE your_table_name  
set description = 
concat
(
substring_index(description, '<a',1), 
substring_index(description, '</a>',-1)
);
```

Comment: But different products has different description that's why I thought regex would be better.

Comment: Your answer is good for selecting records, can you also add query for updating to this ?